# What do each of the actions in the SCCM Client actually do?

Tags: windows, sccm

So this sounds like a simple question but searching the internet I have been unable to find a list of what the different actions in the SCCM Client actually do.

On my machine it is called Configuration Manager and I am specifically talking about the actions tab.

Does someone have a list of each action and what they do? I would find it really helpful to have a reference in one place that I could point some fellow techs too.

Comment: Did yuo try reading the documentation? "Searching the internet" sounds like "i am not going to read the documentation, no, seriously, i ask google" which is not smart for a compelx and professional product like sccm.

Comment: @TomTom I was never given documentation. Also, nice way of saying RTFM. That aside, should I update the questions with the dozens of links that point to other places with massive jargon, and often times a description of one action? That's all I seemed to find.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a deceptively hard question!  If you look up the [Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633241.aspx) regarding the Actions tab, you'll find that it tells you nothing about each action.  All of the actions on the tab are scheduled tasks; that is, if the feature is enabled, it will automatically run on a periodic basis.  In some circumstances (e.g. troubleshooting), you may find the need to manually initiate these tasks.  That's where this tab comes in.  The information on each action's functionality is scattered about the Technet website (although I understand and personally use many of the these actions, I copied from the Technet website because I'm lazy):

> - **[Branch Distribution Point Maintenance Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb681046.aspx)** verifies any prestaged packages and downloads any that do not exist on the branch
>     distribution point.  While Technet does not explicitly state it, I
>     believe this task is useful only on branch distribution points and is
>     ignored on normal clients.
> - **[Discovery Data Collection Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633276.aspx)** causes the client to generate a new discovery data record (DDR).  When the DDR is processed
>     by the site server, Discovery Data Manager adds or updates resource
>     information from the DDR in the site database.
> - **[File Collection Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693889.aspx)** When a file is specified for collection, the Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2007
>     software inventory agent searches for that file when it runs a
>     software inventory scan on each client in the site. If the software
>     inventory client agent finds a file that should be collected, the file
>     is attached to the inventory file and sent to the site server.  This
>     action differs from software inventory in that it actually *sends* the
>     file to the site server, so that it can be later viewed using Resource
>     Explorer.  This is a part of SCCM inventory functionality.
> - **[Hardware Inventory Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632916.aspx)** collects information such as available disk space, processor type, and operating system about each
>     computer.  This is a part of SCCM inventory functionality.
> - **[Machine Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633207.aspx)** The client downloads its policy on a schedule. By default, this value is
>     configured to every 60 minutes and is configured with the option
>     Policy polling interval (minutes). However, there might be occasions
>     when you want to initiate ad-hoc policy retrieval from the client—for
>     example, in a troubleshooting scenario or when testing.  This action
>     initiates ad-hoc *machine* policy retrieval from the client outside
>     its scheduled polling interval.
> - **[Software Inventory Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632607.aspx)** collects software inventory data directly from files (such as .exe files) by inventorying the file
>     header information. Configuration Manager 2007 can also inventory
>     unknown files — files that do not have detailed information in their
>     file headers. This provides a flexible, easy-to-maintain software
>     inventory method. You can also have Configuration Manager 2007 collect
>     copies of files that you specify. Software inventory and collected
>     file information for a client can be viewed using Resource Explorer.
>     This is a part of SCCM inventory functionality.
> - **[Software Metering Usage Report Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb694145.aspx)** collects the data that allows you to monitor and client software usage.
> - **[Software Updates Deployment Evaluation Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb694299.aspx)** initiates a scan for software updates compliance. Before client computers can scan
>     for software update compliance, the software updates environment must
>     be configured.
> - **[Software Updates Scan Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb694299.aspx)** Just after a software update installation completes, a scan is initiated to verify that the update
>     is no longer required and to create a new state message that indicates
>     the update has been installed. When the installation has finished but
>     a restart is necessary, the state will indicate that the client
>     computer is pending a restart.
> - **[User Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633207.aspx)** Similar to Machine Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle, but this action initiates
>     ad-hoc *user* policy retrieval from the client outside its scheduled
>     polling interval.
> - **[Windows Installer Source List Update Cycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892810.aspx)** causes the Product Source Update Manager to complete a full update cycle. When
>     you install an application using Windows Installer, those Windows
>     Installer applications try to return to the path they were installed
>     from when they need to install new components, repair the application,
>     or update the application. This location is called the Windows
>     Installer source location. Windows Installer Source Location Manager
>     can automatically search Configuration Manager 2007 distribution
>     points for the source files, even if the application was not
>     originally installed from a distribution point.

Comment: I hope all of the items are clear.  If not, let me know and I will try to elaborate.  After using SCCM for nearly three years, I will be the first to tell you the Technet documentation SUCKS...

Comment: One thing that seems to confuse people I work with: software installed using Windows Installer and other software in the Add/Remove Programs list is unintuitively inventoried during a *Hardware Inventory Cycle*.

Comment: The Hardware Inventory Cycle is actually a confusing name, what it really means is "WMI Inventory", as it reports any info available via WMI which is primarily hardware related info, but also includes other info accessible via WMI such as Add/Remove Programs, Operating System type and version, Services, etc. Whereas "Software Inventory" really means what most people would think of as a file inventory (except that would be too close to File Collection Inventory, which as you say above is different).

Answer (score 0):

I also found this explanation for the Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle:

Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle – This action re-evaluates the requirement rules for all deployments. If an application is required, and not installed when the Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle runs, Configuration Manager automatically triggers a re-install. The Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle only applies to applications and not to the packages. The default value is set to run every 7 days.