# Configuration Manager not working: "The selected cycle will run and might take several minutes to finish"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

In Windows Server 2012 R2, when going into the following configuration and clicking the "Run Now" button for any actions, I get an informational message dialog that says "The selected cycle will run and might take several minutes to finish." with a dialog title of "Software Updates Scan Cycle".  Even though it says to wait, the server does nothing for hours.  How can I run these so something happens?  All I want to do is check for Windows Updates because the machine says it hasn't been updated in two years.

Control Panel > Configuration Manager > Actions (tabbed panel) > Actions (section)

[image]

## EDIT:

Here's what they do.  But it doesn't help with the issue.

[What do each of the actions in the SCCM Client actually do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/364555/what-do-each-of-the-actions-in-the-sccm-client-actually-do)

Answer (score 1):

In Control Panel > Windows Updates, the "Most recent check for updates" said "Today at 6:01", but the "Updates were installed" said "4/24/2015 at 4:14".  So the system hasn't been updated in awhile.  I found a hyperlink in this screen to "Check online ..." for updates.  This ran through one cycle, and said it failed.  I did it again, and it finally downloaded and installed updates.  Now it says "Updates were installed" of "Today at 7:03".  So that seems good now.

Now after a reboot, when I go into, and select an Action and choose "Run Now", I get an error saying

> The selected option cannot run

So since this is a different error, I will leave that as the answer for now.

Control Panel > Configuration Manager > Actions (tabbed panel) > Actions (section)

Comment: After the restart of SMS Service and waiting a few minutes I was able to rerun the cycles